# How big is cocoapods now? (jun 2016)

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

trying to install cocoapods but I'm already at almost an hour of downloading and 338 mb so far. How big is the completed download as of 2016?
Here's what I know:

```
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

Then it just hangs there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users/Name/.cocoapods/repos >du -h -d 1
780M    ./master`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: hi @abarisone - he answered my question perfectly. .